# Removing fields and buttons from admin dashboard?

Tags: customization

I want a good way to **remove/hide** fields from the admin dashboard on pages like My Sites, Your Profile, Add New (User) etc.
I know it is easy to hide with css, but the problem is that it is also easy to activate again via the browser. So I though about using jQuery to remove them instead.

Tried using the code below without any success:

```
add_action( 'current_screen', 'wpdocs_this_screen' );
function wpdocs_this_screen() {
    $currentScreen = get_current_screen();
    if( $currentScreen->id === "my-sites" ) {
      ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ){
                $('#myblogs').remove();
            } );
        </script>
      <?php
    }
}
```

It is supposed to load when the admin visits **/wp-admin/my-sites.php**
But it does not work. And I tried replacing the jQuery with an alert to easily spot if it was working. But still no go.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: jQuery isn't really any more secure than hiding things with CSS. Why not look into roles and capabilities, and create a new role if you need one, so that only the true site admin has full capabilities and everyone else with lesser roles just can't access anything they're not supposed to?

Comment: I already use roles for this. What I want to do is to simplify the UI for the users on my Multisite and remove unnecessary things which is only confusing. Is it better to hook in to the php somehow?

Comment: It all depends on your goals. If you want to prevent people from accessing certain screens, PHP is the only surefire way - people could have JS off or type in URLs with query strings manually if they want to access things they shouldn't. If the page loads slowly and you're using JS or CSS, all items may show for awhile until those assets load, causing the screen to jump. But when you remove using PHP the items you're trying to hide will always successfully be hidden.